# How to Bulk / Batch Rename in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, batch

I Have Question, How to bulk / batch rename in terminal ? i use ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

example

i have 5 file

```
(GreatSoftware) AVG Anvitirus - 1.exe
(GreatSoftware) Windows Media Payer - 2.exe
(GreatSoftware) Winamp - 3.exe
(GreatSoftware) CorelDraw - 4.exe
(GreatSoftware) Chrome - 5.exe
```

rename to

```
Joesoftware AVG Anvitirus - 1.exe
Joesoftware Windows Media Payer - 2.exe
Joesoftware Winamp - 3.exe
Joesoftware CorelDraw - 4.exe
Joesoftware Chrome - 5.exe
```

please help, I want a script that I understand enough of this problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

To rename, you do not need a script. There is the `rename` command that allows to rename with a single command. It is installed by default. Consult `man rename` for how it works. Useful for first learning is among others, [this website](https://www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/).